# WiX Burn: How to deploy the installer executable to a certain location?

Tags: wix, burn

I have successfully created a chained installation package using WiX 3.7 and Burn. The installer itself uses WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.

Is there a way to deploy (i.e. copy) the whole burn package to a certain location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Burn provides the "Layout" action that will copy all of the Bundle content to a specified directory. The wixstdba does support this action so you can use it like:

```
yourbundle.exe /layout optional\path\to\layout\folder
```

If you don't specify the `optional\path\to\layout\folder` then Burn will layout out to the folder where yourbundle.exe is located.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for your input. That's actually quite helpful, but I'm not at the goal yet. My idea was to deploy it to a location which is defined by a chained msi. So the deployment target evaluation should happen after the chain is installed. I would consider using LaunchTarget, but I always get "Error 0x80070002: Failed to launch target: [...]" in the log, no matter what command I choose to run. Is my usage correct? Either as <Variable Name="LaunchTarget" Value="[...]" /> or in the <bal.WixStandardBootstrapperApplication> attribute, the error is the same.

Comment: There is currently no way to communicate Properties from an MSI to Variables in a Bundle. However, you can do it the other way around. You'd need to get the Variable defined in the Bundle to use it in the LaunchTarget. 0x80070002 means it can't find the file to launch.

Comment: Thanks again for the input. I've decided to create a post-install-script that is executed with the LaunchTarget feature. But the 0x80070002-Problem remains. When I just put "cmd.exe" in LaunchTarget, it works, but when the command is for example "[InstallFolder]\test.cmd [WixBundleOriginalSource]", the log shows that the variables are expanded correctly, but the 0x80070002-error remains. Copying the the expanded LaunchTarget from the log and executing it in a separate command line window works like a charm.

Comment: See question http://stackoverflow.com/q/16031778/23852 for the answer to your 0x80070002 issue. Short answer: `LaunchTarget` cannot contain arguments, `LaunchArguments` is where they have to go.